# Ext.Error: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String

Tags: asp.net, json, extjs4

I am working with ExtJs 4.0. I want to read json file in my chart but gettig following error
**Ext.Error: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String.**

**store n model:**

```
 Ext.define('chartModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 
            {name: 'year'},
            {name: 'comedy'},
            {name: 'action'},
            {name: 'drama'},
            {name: 'thriller'}
    ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: chartModel,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            method: "GET",
            messageProperty: 'jsonData'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

**data.json file:**

```
data: [{year: 2005, comedy: 34000000, action: 23890000, drama: 18450000, thriller: 20060000}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON property names must be quoted to be considered valid. In addition, your `data` needs to be a property of an object, like `{"data":[{"year":2005, "comedy":3400000...`.

**EDIT:** What Neil said is correct. `Ext.decode` does not require property names to be in quotes. However, the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) *does* require them so you should definitely get in the habit of using them.

Comment: extjs's parser doesn't care, actually, but yes, you are correct